# How to make a option slider in HTML5 with 4 states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a mini personal HTML5 website for learning purpose and been stuck at coding a slider that allows 4 options (ranging between good and bad) to be chosen by sliding the button across the bar.

The result should be able to trigger some code for a change in display elsewhere.

I am sure there are many tutorials for this but I can't seem to figure out the correct way to name of the slider. When I search option slider on google I end up with image sliders and or google images of what I want.

I am sure it can't be that tricky but I just can't seem to figure out how to do it as it's my first attempt.

```
<label for="weight">Option</label>
<input id="weight" min="0" value="0" max="3" step="1">
```

Some of the searches I have done: for example: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=range+slider&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEorDrkbbQAhWoJ8AKHbGiDEsQ_AUICSgC&biw=1366&bih=700#tbm=isch&q=option+slider

Comment: Question is impossible to answer without a clear understanding of your slider concept. Then, the whole thing is too broad for this site in the first place.

Comment: Sorry charlietfl, I don't understand what you mean. If mean that you don't understand what I mean by a slider I have given a google image for the same. I tried explaining it best as I can but I really don't know what it's called. All I need need is a simple slider ( line lets say) that has a button on top which can be dragged back and forth to select the given options as shown in the image.

Comment: shouldn't be hard to find lots of variations of those on the web then. Make sure you use the term javascript or html in the search

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
<label for="weight">Option</label>
<input type="range" id="weight" min="0" value="0" max="3" step="1" list="volsettings">
<datalist id="volsettings">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</datalist>
```

The `datalist` simply puts the tick marks in place.  You can "watch" the value, and present which of the four "options" are selected.

Reference: http://thenewcode.com/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input

**EDIT**

Some options for usage: https://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/pcekshy5/

Comment: thanks that works, could you tell how I can write text on either side of the slider please. For example if I want the left side to say good and the right to say bad. Also could you help me with how I would about checking what value has been selected and make it do some sort of function in javascript. for example; if slider = 1 then do this

Comment: These are actually separate questions; I added a fiddle that shows using spans for the good and bad (might need some CSS for styling. Also, showed using the input's value directly (you could have used a case statement or triggered some other code.